# Flutter App not compiling only by changing plugin location

Tags: flutter

I have a flutter app that uses the [maplibre library](https://github.com/maplibre/flutter-maplibre-gl). When I add the library in pubsec.yaml by referencing the github repo as, as shown below, it works.

```
maplibre_gl:
      git:
        url: https://github.com/maplibre/flutter-maplibre-gl.git
        ref: main
```

However, if I download the library, and reference it as a local library, as shown below:

```
maplibre_gl:
    path: ../flutter-maplibre-gl
```

I get the following error:

```
../../../../.pub-cache/git/flutter-maplibre-gl-a32f8d939b580b853ab34a8fb0cc61c66b71d36b/maplibre_gl_platform_interface/lib/src/view_wrappers.dart:130:51: Error: The getter 'requiresViewComposition' isn't defined for the class 'TextureAndroidViewController'.
 - 'TextureAndroidViewController' is from 'package:flutter/src/services/platform_views.dart' ('../../../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/platform_views.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'requiresViewComposition'.
  bool get requiresViewComposition => _controller.requiresViewComposition;
                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

What is weird is that I am only and only changing the referenced library location, nothing else.

Can anyone point out the problem?

Comment: Plugins normally have an example project. If you change directory to flutter-maplibre-gl/example on your local drive, can you run the example?